# str_pad with a float in php?

Tags: php

I am looking for the best way to `str_pad` floats in php.

The problem I am having is that `str_pad` takes into account the string length but with a float there is the decimal point. If I want a number padded with zeros this becomes a little bit of a nightmare.

For example if I need the number to always have at least 6 numbers after the decimal point I cannot do it with `str_pad` as the results change.

```
$i = 1.0;
echo str_pad($i, 8, '0'); // 1.000000
$i = 10.5
echo str_pad($i, 8, '0'); // 10.50000 ## ONLY PADDED WITH 5 NUMBERS AFTER DECIMAL
```

I know I can `explode` then `str_pad` and do it that way but just wondered if there was a php built in function for this or any better ways.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `number_format`

```
echo number_format($i, 6); // 6 decimals
```

You can also automatically add separators and spaces etc

```
number_format($number, 2, ',', ' '); // 1 234,56
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try

```
printf ("%.06f", $i);
```

instead.

Comment: to return the value he probably wants `sprintf`